# Shortcut to activate and deactivate a layer filter

Tags: qgis-3, filter, mapcanvas, shortcuts

I'm looking for the fastest way to filter and unfilter a layer in qgis 3.

My current workflow is too tedious: right click on layer / filter / write filter or delete filter

[image]

My final goal is to see at one sight the results of a filter/unfilter.

Answer (score 2):

You can duplicate/copy your layer when you right-click it. Then filter one layer, and leave the other as it is. Put both layers in a group and set this group to `mutually exclusive` by rightclicking it.